# object to json_encode return false in linux server cakephp 3

Tags: php, json, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I'm facing a horrible problem in Linux server. I don't understand what to do now.

My problem is that in Linux server my script runs properly without any error but when I use an object to JSON encode it returns false.

Please any one help. Thanks in advance.

```
public function ajaxDataSearch() {
    $this->loadModel('ViewDocketHistorys');
    $this->render(false);
    $this->viewBuilder()->layout('false');
    if ($this->request->is(['post'])) {
        $DocketNo = $this->request->data['DocketNo'];

       $SearchData = $this->ViewDocketHistorys->find()
                ->where(['DocketNo' => $DocketNo])
                ->last();
        $Jsondate = json_encode($SearchData);
        echo $Jsondate;
    }
}
```

When I debug query data

```
debug($SearchData); exit;
```

output:

```
object(App\Model\Entity\ViewDocketHistory) {
'MasterID' => (int) 311,
'DocketNo' => 'fhfghfghf',
'[new]' => false,
'[accessible]' => [
    '*' => true
],
'[dirty]' => [],
'[original]' => [],
'[virtual]' => [],
'[errors]' => [],
'[invalid]' => [],
'[repository]' => 'ViewDocketHistorys'}
```

When I debug JSON encode

```
debug($Jsondate); exit;
```

Output:

```
false
```

Comment: Debug the problem by checking `json_last_error()` and `json_last_error_msg()` after calling `json_encode()`.

Comment: its says error 8 (Type not supported)

Comment: Good, now inspect `$SearchData->jsonSerialize()` to figure what the unsporrted type may be.

Comment: I found the data type problem in database, Some column convert BLOB data type when run database in Linux server but still working in windows server, I thing that BLOB data type is the main problem i found. Now the problem is why my column convert BLOB form in view table, I selected int data type but that converted BLOB data type when creating view in Linux and varchar(255) in windows, I check all table column that are same but don't understand why its converted, if you find this problem please help me, that is the 4th day facing the bullshit problem. Sorry and Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Last found a solution When I create a view with a UNION, i have to make sure the data types of the corresponding columns are the same (or at least, similar enough for one to be converted to the other). In the current case, the first column of the view is a 'column1', and no data type definition apart from BLOB can make much sense of that.

If you really need this as a view, you could try...

```
SELECT e.ID AS ID, 
   NULL        AS table_field,
   ...etc...
   'e'         AS type
FROM table1 AS e
 UNION ALL
 SELECT
    NULL         AS ID,
    k.table_field AS table_field, 
   ...etc...
   'k'          AS type
 FROM table2 AS k;
```

Details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280212/blob-in-mysql-view-instead-of-the-proper-data)

Answer (score 0):

You can try by doing:

```
$Jsondate = json_encode($SearchData->toArray());
```

->toArray() will convert entity class into a clean array, after that, json_decode would receive the right structure to JavaScript Object Notation.

Comment: i am trying but my problem is data field, and that's problem solved it, i posted before comment.